# Summarizing time series data from multiple sites with irregular time interval based on conditions

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, time-series, tidyr

I have time-series data with rainfall, runoff, and soil moisture from multiple locations. I am trying to go through the data and when there is rainfall (>0), I would like to do the following. 1) calculate the change in soil moisture (SM after rain – SM before the rain) and 2) sum runoff after a single rain event.  I have the following code working but the issue is, it doesn’t do the job by location. For example, on the last day (2023-01-10) for Site A, it calculates the change in SM by taking SM from Site B. Also, it takes the runoff from Site B. Most importantly, if I want to sum all runoff measurements after a single rainfall event until the next rain occurs, how can I do that?

```
#Load libraries
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

#Sample data
df <- data.frame(date = rep(seq(as.Date("2023-01-01"), as.Date("2023-01-10"), by = "day"),times=2),
      Site = rep(c('A','B'), each=10),
      rainfall = c(0, 2, 0, 15, 0, 28, 0, 0, 0, 3,3, 0, 5, 30, 35, 10, 8, 0, 0, 0),
      runoff = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0,1, 0, 0, 1, 15, 16,8, 3, 0, 0),
      moisture = c(0.2, 0.25, 0.3, 0.22, 0.15, 0.28, 0.3, 0.4, 0.2, 0.15,0.15, 0.2, 0.25, 0.3, 0.35, 0.1, 0.08, 0.12, 0.4, 0.5))

#code to get moisutre change (after rainfall - before rainfall) & runoff (after a single rainfall event) `
summary_data <- df %>%
dplyr::group_by(Site) %>%
mutate(moisture_change = ifelse(rainfall > 0, lag(moisture) - lead(moisture), NA),
runoff_total = ifelse(rainfall>0, lead(runoff),NA))l>0, lead(runoff),NA))
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a few problems with your code:

1. with `ifelse(rainfall > 0, lag(moisture) - lead(moisture), NA)`, it works if it only rains for one day, but what happens in situations in which it rains on consecutive days?
2. you never create a rain group column, and
3. you then never group by that column

I fixed those things in my code below:

```
df %>%
  mutate(before_moisture = lag(moisture),
         after_moisture = lead(moisture),
         rain_event = cumsum((is.na(lag(rainfall)) | lag(rainfall) == 0) & rainfall > 0), .by = Site) %>%
  mutate(total_runoff = sum(runoff),
         total_rainfall = sum(rainfall),
         before_moisture = first(before_moisture),
         after_moisture = last(after_moisture), .by = c(Site, rain_event)) 

# Output:
         date Site rainfall runoff moisture before_moisture after_moisture
1  2023-01-01    A        0      0     0.20              NA           0.25
2  2023-01-02    A        2      0     0.25            0.20           0.22
3  2023-01-03    A        0      0     0.30            0.20           0.22
4  2023-01-04    A       15      0     0.22            0.30           0.28
5  2023-01-05    A        0      5     0.15            0.30           0.28
6  2023-01-06    A       28      0     0.28            0.15           0.15
7  2023-01-07    A        0     10     0.30            0.15           0.15
8  2023-01-08    A        0      0     0.40            0.15           0.15
9  2023-01-09    A        0      0     0.20            0.15           0.15
10 2023-01-10    A        3      0     0.15            0.20             NA
11 2023-01-01    B        3      1     0.15              NA           0.25
12 2023-01-02    B        0      0     0.20              NA           0.25
13 2023-01-03    B        5      0     0.25            0.20             NA
14 2023-01-04    B       30      1     0.30            0.20             NA
15 2023-01-05    B       35     15     0.35            0.20             NA
16 2023-01-06    B       10     16     0.10            0.20             NA
17 2023-01-07    B        8      8     0.08            0.20             NA
18 2023-01-08    B        0      3     0.12            0.20             NA
19 2023-01-09    B        0      0     0.40            0.20             NA
20 2023-01-10    B        0      0     0.50            0.20             NA
   rain_event total_runoff total_rainfall
1           0            0              0
2           1            0              2
3           1            0              2
4           2            5             15
5           2            5             15
6           3           10             28
7           3           10             28
8           3           10             28
9           3           10             28
10          4            0              3
11          1            1              3
12          1            1              3
13          2           43             88
14          2           43             88
15          2           43             88
16          2           43             88
17          2           43             88
18          2           43             88
19          2           43             88
20          2           43             88
```